# creating unmarshaller using circe

Tags: scala, akka-http, circe

I am playing with Akka Http client side. I have created a simple request but how can I unmarshal the respose? in the server side it is easy to use circe to marshal the response, but I have difficulties in the client side

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.Uri.Query
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshal
import akka.stream.Materializer

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext


class QuestionsFetcher {

  import de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpcirce.CirceSupport._
  import io.circe.generic.auto._

  val baseUrl = "https://somewhere.com"


 def fetch(tag: String)(implicit ac: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer) = {

implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ac.dispatcher

val fromDate = DateTime.now.minus(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
val uri = Uri(baseUrl).withQuery(Query("order"->"desc"))
val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, uri)

Http().singleRequest(request)
    .map(r => Unmarshal(r.entity.withContentType(ContentTypes.`application/json`)).to[Items])
```

}
}

When running the code I am getting 
ErrorFuture(io.circe.ParsingFailure: expected json value got  (line 1, column 1))

Comment: Are you using [akka-http-circe](https://github.com/hseeberger/akka-http-json/tree/master/akka-http-circe)?

Comment: Yes I am using akka-http-circe

Comment: Can you say a little more about your imports? Can you resolve an `Encoder[Items]` in the same scope?

Answer (score 0):

the content was gziped - so after running the decoder flow
it was ok